# Why does flutter use dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I understand that there could be many reasons but when the developer community has already adopted ES6 and is working hard to make it better then why dart and not JS?

Is there anything special which makes dart such a good fit for Flutter?

Comment: https://flutter.io/faq/#why-did-flutter-choose-to-use-dart

Comment: Not sure why you wrote ES6 and "dart js". Flutter has nothing to do with JavaScript. While Dart can be compiled to JavaScript, Flutter doesn't use this feature.

Answer (score 13):

That's an FAQ and already answered extensively

- https://flutter.io/faq/#why-did-flutter-choose-to-use-dart
- https://hackernoon.com/why-flutter-uses-dart-dd635a054ebf

I'm not sure why you wrote ES6 and "dart js".

Flutter has nothing to do with JavaScript.
While Dart can be compiled to JavaScript, Flutter doesn't use this feature.

For Flutter Dart is compiled to native binary code.

Comment: And a huge benefit is that Dart language can change to improve flutter.

Comment: Thanks above links helped me to understand it better,  sorry I missed docs

Comment: @RémiRousselet you made a convincing point! 

Comment: then how does it run inside a browser? it compiles to webassembly or what?

Comment: @pavel_orekhov Dart was designed from the start to be easily transpilable to JS. Dart also from the start had an intetpreter to run on the command line. Later they added a compiler that generates machine code. Flutter uses the interpreter for debug builds on most platforms and the compiler for release builds. For the web it transpiles to JS.

Answer (score 7):

I did a little research after being asked the question by a couple of colleagues and thought it would help by summarising what I have read and thought about (it's a very important question for my colleagues)

Language requirements for Flutter

- AOT and JIT compilation for fast reload and fast released code
- A good garbage collector to clean up after creating and destroying many objects
- Single threaded to avoid locks and therefore jank
- An arm compiler to avoid having another engine running the code on the device (aka React Native)

Dart meets all these requirements.  JS (I think) meets all the above pretty closely too, apart from the AOT and JIT compiler part.

Why didn't Flutter choose JS and build a JIT and AOT compiler?  (initially they did choose JS but they switched)  I could guess at the following...

- Dart was built with to-binary compilation in mind from the beginning
- Dart already had a to-binary JIT compiler, it added the AOT compiler later
- Dart is more structured and simpler (it is type safe and has no eval)
- JS could implement new language features that might jeopardise flutter dev
- Dart can be optimized for Flutter without needing to worry about other uses of JS
- Historically long wait times for new JS functionality (last 3 years has been better)
- The Dart and Flutter teams can work together closely

Saying all of that I can imagine that a JS solution could happen but it might be costly and a more complicated solution.  Dart is pretty good and Dart2 has really improved things with inherent type safety.

Comment: "JS (I think) meets all the above pretty closely too". Can you compile JS to (efficient) native code?

Comment: Is that because there is an AOT compiler that was created by the Dart team or is that an inherent property of Dart as the language?  Could the Flutter team have chosen JS and created an AOT compiler for JS, I detailed the reasons below as to my guesses on why Flutter chose Dart over JS to build it's AOT.  (I might be missing something though!)

Comment: It's just a personal opinion, but it's popularity would probably be the only reason to chose JavaScript. Dart is strongly typed which makes it much easier to write correct programs. Dart was built with to-JS and to-binary compilation in mind from the beginning. to-binary was only JIT before Dart 2 though. iOS doesn't allow JIT except for JS. There seem to be ways to compile JS to native (I found https://github.com/lastmjs/node-compiler) but anyway. Why chosing JS if there are alternatives ;-)

Comment: ah!  I didn't know that Dart was built for to-binary compilation from the beginning I thought it was just to-JS, that's cool and that must be a good reason for its choice in Flutter (I updated my answer).  I guess any inherent language features in Dart have always had that in mind.  Strongly typed languages are a must.  As an OO language I think Dart is very nice.  Thanks for the additional info :-)

Answer (score 0):

Dart has a declarative and programmable layout that is easy to read and visualize. Hence, Flutter doesn't require a separate declarative layout language like XML. It is easy for Flutter to provide advanced tooling since all the layout in one language and in a central place

Answer (score 0):

Dart is much faster than JavaScript, as it can be compiled both AOT and JIT which helps building apps in several ways as using JIT compilation can speed up development and AOT compilation can be used during the release process for better optimization. This technique has been used in Flutter.

**follow the link**

https://medium.com/hackernoon/why-flutter-uses-dart-dd635a054ebf

https://insights.daffodilsw.com/blog/why-flutter-uses-dart